# How do I store the currently logged in user in my table?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Please have patience I am new at MVC. I have created a model called "Book" which represents a text book, in my IdentityModel I added this:

```cs
public class User : IUser
{

// ...

[Key]
public string Id { get; set; }

public string UserName { get; set; }

// Code First will use this to create a foreign key in book
public virtual ICollection<Book> Uploaders { get; set; }

}
```

This created a foreign key in my Books table which is what I wanted. Now in my book controller I simply want to link the book to the user when they hit "create". This is where I am stuck

```cs
//
// POST: /Book/Create
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Book book)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Save uploader here
        // book.Uploader = User.Identity;

        db.Books.Add(book);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(book);
}
```

Comment: What does your `Book` model look like?

Comment: Book model: http://pastie.org/private/zmlggavnes65vhmfy5e6lg

Answer (score 0):

on your Book Model:

```
public virtual User User {get;set;}
public int UserId {get;set;}
```

and assign that in your Controller.

```
book.User = User;
```

Comment: In my controller on this line "book.User = User;" I get "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal' to 'EDU_Rent.Models.User'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)" Also the new UserID int is not any type of foreign key in my DB.

Comment: I cant access db.Users from my controller because my RentContext class doesnt contain the Users DbSet, the IdentityModels does. For refrence, im using all the default user stuff that comes with a new MVC 5 project. Also, im trying to use the currently logged in user, not one that I pick by hand from the DB, the default UserId attribute in the Users table is a string, not an int.

Comment: Sounds like a lot of work but its not.  Why not create a BaseController that gets you access to all the db contexts that you need then inherit your controllers from this so you just you can have DRY code...

Comment: Then I might as well start from scratch and delete all the stuff that comes with the project. There are a lot of nice built in features like roles. Plus if I created that BaseController class I couldnt use a Scaffold to create my book views for me

Comment: if User.Identity.UserID existed this would be trivial. Id grab the user ID, store it in my foreign key and be done.

Comment: i've never done a project where the default scaffolding and built in template fit the business requirements and it sounds like you're finding the same...

Comment: I agree. I was hoping I could use scaffolding as a base and tweak it how I saw fit. Instead, its turned into a bit of a nightmare. Plus this is how I learned because this is how its all taught from the Microsoft MVC 5 tutorials

Answer (score 0):

The userId of the current user can be found in the claims of the User property of the Controller.

Assuming the model:

```
public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual BookUser User { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}
```

You can then set the UserId:

```
//
// POST: /Book/Create
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Authorize] // must be authenticated to be able to set UserId
public ActionResult Create(Book book)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
       UserId = ((ClaimsPrincipal)User).FindFirst(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value`

       db.Books.Add(book);
       db.SaveChanges();
       return RedirectToAction("Index");
   }

   return View(book);
}
```